# My code is printing every word and it shouldn't be

Tags: java

Basically, I wrote code that scans a document and then checks to see if it's what I've called a 'proper' word. A proper word is a word that only has letters but can be followed by whatever punctuation. So 'hello' and 'for4893859.;.;;.' would be proper words, but 'hi,jack' and 'anti-thing' wouldn't be proper words. The code is only supposed to print the proper word, but for some reason, I think it's skipping the for loop and just printing all the words.

```
Scanner test= new Scanner(new File("Test.txt"));
    while(test.hasNext()) {
        String word=test.next();
        char [] curr=word.toCharArray();
        boolean check1=false;
        boolean check2=false;
        for(int i=0; i<curr.length; i++) {

            if(!Character.isLetter(curr[i])) {
                check1=true;
                System.out.println(check1);
                continue;
            }
            if(check1 && Character.isLetter(curr[i])) {
                check2=true;
                System.out.println(check2);
                break;
            }
        }
        if((check1 && !check2)||(!check1 && !check2)) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Which line and variable values caused the code to start doing something you didn't expect?

Comment: Note that in your line `if(check1 && Character.isLetter(curr[i])) {`, `Character.isLetter(curr[i])` will always be true, so this line is the same as `if(check1) {`

Comment: check1 and check2 are singularly uncommunicative names.

Comment: `(check1 && !check2)||(!check1 && !check2)` is equivalent to `!check2`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure just what your logic is supposed to be doing.  Since your issue is with the boolean logic regarding if you print a word or not, I think it will be helpful for you to refactor your boolean logic to be more clear.  There are two places you can do that, on both your second and third **if** expressions.  Here's an equivalent version of your code:

```
Scanner test= new Scanner(new File("Test.txt"));
while(test.hasNext()) {
    String word=test.next();
    char [] curr=word.toCharArray();
    boolean check1=false;
    boolean check2=false;
    for(int i=0; i<curr.length; i++) {

        if(!Character.isLetter(curr[i])) {
            check1=true;
            System.out.println(check1);
            continue;
        }
        if(check1) {
            check2=true;
            System.out.println(check2);
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!check2) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
```

What this logic seems to say is to not print any word that contains a non-letter character followed by at least one letter character.

Answer (score -2):

Its hard to read even simple boolean logic sometimes, but it seems that `(check1 && !check2)||(!check1 && !check2)` boils down to be `!check2`...so perhaps your logic for that check needs to change.

Comment: Also `(check1 && !check2)||(!check1 && !check2)`, here it doesn't matter what the value of check1 would be, because the condition is evaluated with both values of check1, like `(check1 == true && !check2)  || (check1 == false && !check2)`, so check1 will be either true or false, so it simply is `if ( ! check2 )`

Comment: Ha!  @Juseeth beat me to the punch.  I erased my original comment because it said the same thing.  But what he doesn't say clearly is **this answer is wrong**.  It is not true that the **if** will always be executed.

Comment: I am open to being wrong....what combination of true/false would cause (check1 && !check2)||(!check1 && !check2) to evaluate to anything but true?

Comment: **check2 == true**.  As @Juseeth says, this expression simplifies down to **!check2**.  The point, which you were making, is that the value of the expression is independent of **check1**.

Comment: Cool.  I took away my comment on the question saying that your answer isn't correct, as now it is correct.  Thanks for fixing it! - and all of this made your point.  It IS often hard to read even simple boolean logic, lol.